# Union subquery conditioned

Tags: sql, subquery, union, conditional-statements

I am truing to make a case from a union sub query but I can't get to it. I want to make something like this :

```
select t.colA, t.colB,
case when t1.colC = 1 and t2.colC=0 then 1
else t.colC end colC
from 
(
select t1.colA,t1.colB,t1.colC from table1 t1
union all
select t2.colA,t2.colB,t2.colC from table2 t2
) t
```

Is something like this possible ? Or is there any other way ? I absolutely need that union and the case.

Thanks.

Comment: execute and check it out man

Comment: Why not use the case directly in inner query with case ??

Comment: Why do you need the union? It looks more like you need an inner join.

Comment: t1 columns aren't available outside sub-query.

Comment: @CoderofCode Still can't be done. They're totally separate tables in totally separate queries, they just happen to be UNIONed together; you can't reference columns from both in the two separate queries.

Comment: What's the actual task you're trying to complete? What are these tables? How do they link together? What's your sample input data and expected output data?

Comment: It sounds more like you want a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference `t1` and `t2` in your outer SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve your goal with a union.
In a union, you get each line of t1 als a single line in your result, as well as every single line of t2.

If you need to compare a value of a line in t1 and at the same time a value of t2 you have to use a join to merge lines of t1 and lines of t2 together.

Then you are able to do your comparison.

We can help you if you show in detail, WHAT exacly you have as input and want as output

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it the way you want then you can't refer to t1 or t2, you have to reference the aliased subquery which you can do in the following way:

```
select t.colA, t.colB,
case when t.colC = 1 and t.colD is null then 1
else t.colD end colC
from 
(
select t1.colA,t1.colB,t1.colC, null as colD from table1 t1
union all
select t2.colA,t2.colB, null, t2.colC from table2 t2
) t
```